# Need to pull variable count of records from different county

Tags: sql-server

I have a Table called purchaselist which has the county FIPS and lastName  count of mostfrequentlastname.

```
Fips    mdLASTNAME  MOST_FREQUENT rn
37109   SMITH                           953 1
37109   JOHNSON                         496 2
37109   WILLIAMS                        376 3
37109   BROWN                           354 4
37109   WILSON                          315 8
37119   BURNS                           535 162
37119   BRADLEY                         534 163
37119   WATKINS                         531 164
37119   STEELE                          529 165
37119   BERRY                           528 166
```

I need to pull 953 records with lastname Smith from FIPS 37109 and 
496 records with lastname JOHNSON from FIPS 37109 and 
528 records with lastname Berry from FIPS 37119 and so no 
from the table called customer.

```
declare lineCursor12 cursor
fast_forward
for 
select DISTINCT FIPS from #temp5 

declare @Fips varchar(5)

open lineCursor12
fetch next from lineCursor12 into @Fips 
       while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
       begin                  
                     insert into dbo.test
                     Select * from dbo.Customer
                     where  mdFips=@Fips ORDER BY MOST_FREQUENT desc)




                     fetch next from lineCursor12 into @Fips
       end

close lineCursor12
deallocate lineCursor12
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: [Need an Answer? Actually, No … You Need a Question](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer/)

Comment: Do you want the first one in each group with first being defined as the "most frequent"?

Comment: I was able to figure out how to do this out

Answer (score 0):

declare lineCursor12 cursor
fast_forward
for 
select FIPS,[MOST_FREQUENT] ,[LASTNAME] from [Workspace].[dbo].[EriclastName2] where FIPS in ('37119','37109')

declare @Fips varchar(5)
declare @MOST_FREQUENT int 
declare @LASTNAME varchar(50)

open lineCursor12
fetch next from lineCursor12 into @Fips,@MOST_FREQUENT,@LASTNAME
       while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
       begin

```
                 set rowcount @MOST_FREQUENT
                 insert into dbo.finallastname


                 Select [aFIRSTNAME],[aMIDDLEINITIAL],[aLASTNAME],[NameCat],[aFips] from dbo.consumer
                 WITH(INDEX(IX_aLastName_aFips))
                 where aFips=@Fips and [aLASTNAME]= @LASTNAME 
                 Set rowcount 0



                 fetch next from lineCursor12 into @Fips,@MOST_FREQUENT,@LASTNAME
   end
```

close lineCursor12
deallocate lineCursor12